# xmega-E5: exposed pad

Tags: avr, packages, xmega, pad

I'm drawing my own CAD library for the [ATXMEGA*-E5](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/268/Atmel-8153-8-and-16-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-XMEGA--1315766.pdf) devices.
At page 69 (Seztion 35.2 32Z) there is the drawing of the package 32Z (5x5mm 32-lead VQFN).

I cannot find any information about the connection of the exposed pad. Searching "pad" in the whole document return nothing.

Is there a way to understand if it's connected to GND? I think if it was *mandatory* to connect it externally it should be written... Perhaps is there for thermal reasons only?

Comment: There's no indication that the square shape in the middle is a "pad" at all. The only documentation associated with it is related to showing the pin-1 orientation of the chip. I wouldn't make any attempt to solder it to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/32L_VQFN_5x5x0_9mm_3_1EP_UBB_C04-21395b.pdf) shows the footprint dimensions.  They appear to consider the "thermal pad" optional; since there's no instructions on connecting it, I'd let it float if you use it.